# how to save pandas profiling report after I have run it without ref variable?

Tags: pandas

```
%%time
train.profile_report()# I run it without referencing in variable.
```

it took 1h 15min to generate the report because it has 200 000 rows, 122 columns.
How to save it after I have run it? I run the cell without saving it in variable.
I could do this, but did not:

```
d = train.profile_report()
d.to_file(output_file="output.html")
```

Is there way to reference the entire cell?

Answer (score 1):

you could access your local variable using the `globals()` command, you would have to fetch all the variables there till you find it, I guess it would be under some underscore name, you could narrow down your search if you report has some structure, for example it has a particular type, you could get the local variables having the same type using

```py
 [x for x in globals() if type(globals()[x]) is your_type]
```

in your case, I guess you could access it using

```py
l = [x for x in globals() if type(globals()[x]) is \
         pandas_profiling.__init__.ProfileReport]
```

you could then access your candidate variables as `globals()[x]` where x is from `l`